# Scan serial ports from my computer with node

Tags: node.js, error-handling, coffeescript, serial-port

I have this code, opening the serial port 38, and listing pors on my computer. This works prety well.

```
sp = serialPort.SerialPort
  port = new sp('COM38', baudrate : 9600, bufferSize : 1000000)
  serialPort.list (err, ports) ->
    ports.forEach (port) ->
      console.log port.comName
      if port.comName is 'COM38'
        console.log 'Douchette USB connectée'
```

Now, the device on this serialport 38 isn't always connected to my computer. How can i handle error from the line `port = new sp('COM38', baudrate : 9600, bufferSize : 1000000)` ?

I mean, when i try to create a new sp on COM38 if there is nothing on COM38, i need to know it to do something like

```
if error
  console.log 'Devise is not connected'`
```

Any ideas ?

I am using serialport from npm. npmjs.com/package/serialport

Comment: I am using serialport from npm. https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport I didn't found anything about connecting ports that have nothing on them

Comment: Edit that information *into* the question. Good luck.